# Do we have to use ScrollableResults for batch update?

Tags: hibernate

I'm reading this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html about hibernate batching. The batch udpate section says

> For retrieving and updating data, the same ideas apply. In addition,
>   you need to use scroll() to take advantage of server-side cursors for
>   queries that return many rows of data.

Does it mean we have to use ScrollableResults to enable batch update? Or it just means that using it gives us more advatanges?

Thanks,
Sarah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the documentation states is that it is very easy to get an `OutOfMemoryError` when trying to batch update using `select` that return many rows.

By using the `ScrollableResults` you can iterate those rows and retrieve them only when reached.

It is not mandatory thou. If you look at the examples it is only to iterate entities, then those entities are updated and the session flushed.

So if you use `scroll()` or store all the rows in a `List` is up to you. I would recommend `ScrollableResultSet`.